# NLog config inside web.config or app.config ignored in version 4.5.11

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config, nlog

Recently, we've updated some web and console application, to use a newer version of NLog, the latest 4.5.11.
Before, we've used a 4.4 version.

With this 4.4 version, we were able to set the NLog config inside the web.config or app.config file. 
According to the documentation, this is still possible. However, with the newer version this does not work.
I only get some logging, if I copy/paste the same rules, into an nlog.config file.

Of course, I could do this for all my applications, but there is a chance we miss something.
What is the cause it isn't read from the web/app.config file anymore?

I also tried to set the `throwExceptions="true"` attribute, but it gave me no exceptions.

Also if I set the internal log file, on the  attribute inside my web.config, it's still not working. The internal log, is also empty.
Tested with `internalLogLevel="Info"` and `internalLogLevel="Trace"`

If I set it in the `Application_Start`, I only have

```
2019-02-27 10:23:33.1899 Info Shutting down logging...
2019-02-27 10:23:33.1899 Info Logger has been shut down.
```

This is my Web.Config (partly)

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>
...
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt" internalLogLevel="Info">
   <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Log/${shortdate}.log" layout="${date:format=dd-MM-yyyy HH\:mm\:ss.fff} [${level}] ${callsite} ${message}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=tostring}}" />
    <target name="warnfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Log/warn/${shortdate}.log" layout="${date:format=dd-MM-yyyy HH\:mm\:ss.fff} [${level}] ${callsite} ${message}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=tostring}}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile">
        <filters>
          <when condition="contains('${message}', 'ThreadAbortException')" action="Ignore" />
        </filters>
      </logger>
      <logger name="*" level="Debug" writeTo="warnfile">
        <filters>
          <when condition="contains('${message}', 'ThreadAbortException')" action="Ignore" />
        </filters>
      </logger>
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Comment: Pretty sure app.config loading is still working. So I think you have made other changes than updating NLog. Please check the NLog InternalLogger: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging (Maybe have to configure it at runtime, and make sure to enable it before creating the first NLog Logger object along with static ones)

Comment: @RolfKristensen See my edit about the internal log

Comment: You should post the `app.config` that you're using.  I've noticed in some cases that upgrading nuget packages have added duplicated sections to my configs - having 2 nlog sections caused issues.

Comment: @BrendanGreen I've only one <nlog> section in my config.

Comment: Could you check the File Properties of NLog.dll and see the Assembly Title if it says `NLog for .NET Framework 4.5` or `NLog for NetStandard 2.0` ?

Comment: Instead of making the NLog InternalLogger test with the WebApp, then please try with the ConsoleApp (As you say both are not working). You should have better control with enabling the InternalLogger in Program.cs-main-method before creating the first NLog-Logger-object.